# how to serialize and deserialize a list of object in c# using json

Tags: c#, json, bluetooth-lowenergy

I would like to serialize a Bluetooth `DeviceInformation`
list in json to save it in a file and be able to reopen the file and deserialize it

```
public void BluetoothClientSerialization()
{
    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        WriteIndented = true,
            Converters = {
                new JsonStringEnumConverter()
            }
    };
    string fileName = "BluetoothClient.json";
    string jsonRead = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    DeviceInformation weatherForecast = JsonSerializer.Deserialize < DeviceInformation >
        (jsonRead);

    var jsonWrite = JsonSerializer.Serialize < List < DeviceInformation >>
        (ListDeviceInformation, options);
    File.WriteAllText(fileName, jsonWrite);



}

public void BluetoothClientDeserialize()
{

    JsonSerializerOptions options = new JsonSerializerOptions
    {
        Converters = {
            new JsonStringEnumConverter()
        }
    };
    string fileName = "BluetoothClient.json";
    var jsonString = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
    if (jsonString != "")
    {
        ListDeviceInformation = JsonSerializer.Deserialize < List < DeviceInformation >>
            (jsonString, options);
    }

}
```

my problem is when i deserialize it puts me:

> System.NotSupportedException : 'Deserialization of types without a parameterless constructor, a singular parameterized constructor, or a parameterized constructor annotated with 'JsonConstructorAttribute' is not supported. Type 'Windows.Devices.Enumeration.DeviceInformation'. Path: $[0] | LineNumber: 1 | BytePositionInLine: 3.'

How I can solve it

Comment: Make your own class and copy the data into it.